# First chance exception MessageBox on a handled exception

Tags: .net, exception

Lately (past few days) I have encountered a problem on several computers, where an application I wrote shows in some cases a MessageBox with "First chance exception", although the exception occurred in try/catch block (The exception occurred in the try block). There was nothing new in the application, especially in the parts where this occurs.
The application was compiled in debug.
I'm guessing maybe some windows update could have caused this?
Additional information:
One place this occurred was in the following block:

```
try
            {
                result = (ResultCodes) typeof (T).GetMethod(funcName).Invoke(null, args);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {}
```

The functioned called by the invoke ran successfully, however it returned void, which caused the exception. The code above and the function called have not changed for the past year. The function called always returned void.

Comment: I think that your question is rather vague. How we can suppose to diagnose such problem without any insight on what you code does at the moment of the exception.?

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause.
I had an AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException which wrote to a log, and i changed it to open a message box. This event is called also for handled exceptions.